# Does titanic hydra also do damage to the main unit hit or only to the surrounding units?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

Does titanic hydra also do damage to the main unit hit or only to the surrounding units? I'm not sure what splash damage mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It also deal damage to the primary target

As per the [teamfight tactics wiki](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Template:TFT_Data/Titanic_Hydra) for Tytanic Hydra :

> Basic attacks deal 10% of your maximum health bonus damage **to the target** and all adjacent enemies.

And to adress XtremBaumer's answer, in the basic League of Legends game, the [Tytanic Hydra](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Titanic_Hydra) deal bonus damage to target on hit, even if this effect may be considered faintly separated from the cone aoe.

Comment: @Harry Ho, sorry to didn't answer earlier then.